# Can we always find pairs of intersecting subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, matching-theory

This simple-to-state question has been bugging me the whole day: Consider a set $S$ of $2n$ elements and let $F$ be the family of all $k$-size subsets of $S$, for some $1 < k \le n$.

**Question:** Is it possible to pair-up the sets in $F$ such that each pair has a nonempty intersection? (If $|F|$ is odd, we allow one set to be paired with itself.)

Comment: You need some more assumptions, $k=1$ will never work. It should be easy to see that $k=2$ is ok ($n\geq 4$) by writing the subsets in lexicographic order.

Comment: The amount of subsets of size k is not always even, so you can't always pair them up.

Comment: @JanTheMan: yes, that's why there is the remark at the end: If $||$ is odd, we allow one set to be paired with itself.

Comment: Are you familiar with matchings in graph theory?

Comment: @hardmath: Yes. It seems that one could rephrase the question to say whether there exists a perfect matching in the graph consisting of the vertices given by $F$ and edges between all pairs of sets that intersect. But is the existence of a perfect matching obvious in this graph?

Comment: I would think about it in those terms, but the "obvious" idea I have is somehow split the $k$-subsets into two equal size subsets (parts) and apply the "marriage theorem" for regular bipartite graphs. So, no it isn't "obvious" but approaching it in terms of a perfect matching would be attractive.

Comment: @hardmath: I think it can be shown as follows: Since the graph formed by the $k$-subsets is symmetric (this should hold but I haven't proved it), it is also vertex-transitive. Then, according to [this source](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html) it holds that *"Every connected vertex-transitive graph on an even number of vertices has a perfect matching"*

Comment: That is the sort of context that would greatly improve your statement of the problem.  Readers will have an easier time responding if they know your have researched it to that level.

Comment: @Arun That is correct, you have solved your question! The $k$-subset graph is obviously vertex-transitive. For any two subsets $A$ and $B$ with size $k$, you can find a bijection from $A$ to $B$, and extend that to a bijection from $f:S\to S$. Then, $f$ will define a automorphism of the $k$-subset graph sending $A$ to $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the comment of ajr provides the idea for a proof of the general case. In particular, we can explicitely construct a list of the subsets with the additional property that any two consecutive elements have a non-empty intersection. Then, a greedy grouping of elements along this list will do.

Let $n >= 2$ and fix $k$ such that $1 < k <=n$. Wlog, let $S = \{1, 2, ..., 2n \}$ and consider the set $F$ of all $k$-subsets of $S$.

We define $F_1 = \{ f \in F : 1 \in f \}$ and $F_i = \{ f \in F : 1, \dots, i - 1 \notin F, i \in F \}$ for all $2 <= i <= 2n - k + 1$. Notice that for all $1 <= i <= 2n - k + 1$ we have that $F_i$ is non-empty. Moreover, all $F_i$'s are disjoint but together make up all of $F$. Additionally, for all $1 <= i < 2n - k + 1$ the set $F_i$ contains distinct elements $f_i^{i + 1} \neq f_i^{2n}$ such that $i + 1 \in f_i^{i + 1}$ and $2n \in f_i^{2n}$. The set $F_{2n - k + 1}$ contains a single element $f_{2n - k + 1}^{2n -k + 2} = f_{2n - k + 1}^{2n} = \{2n - k + 1, 2n -k + 2, \dots, 2n\}$.

Now consider listing all elements from $F_1$ from $f_1^2$ to $f_1^{2n}$. Append to that list all elements from $F_2$ starting from $f_2^{2n}$ to $f_2^3$. Next, all elements from $F_3$ starting from $f_3^4$ to $f_3^{2n}$. Continue in this alternating fashion to obtain a list $L$ of all items in $F$. Notice now that any two consecutive elements $l_p, l_{p + 1}$ in this list $L$ have non-empty intersection: If they both belong to the same $F_i$ then they share the number $i$. Otherwise, our construction guarantees that they either share the number $i + 1$ (where $l_p \in F_i$) or $2n$.

Since any two consecutive elements have non-empty intersection, we can group consecutive elements together greedily starting at the beginning of $L$.

Of course this could also be formulated in graph-theory terms: We explicitely constructed a Hamiltonian path in the graph where vertices correspond to $k$-subsets and edges exists between vertices with non-empty intersection. Of course, such a Hamiltonian path directly yields the desired nearly-perfect matching.